# How to match person name and surname separately using Regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to get name and surname from a string using RegEx event there are two names. There must be two groups as name and surname for pattern.

I tried below pattern but it gets the last space what I want to remove, but I cannot do it. How can I get the both name and surname correctly?

**What I tried:**

```
^([A-Za-z]+ )+
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Try using `^([A-Za-z ]+) ([A-Za-z]+)$`.

Comment: How is the program meant to know what parts of the name are a part of the surname and which ones are given names? What if the person doesn't even have a surname?

Comment: What if the person has other characters than A-Z in their name?

Comment: What if you had https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akon? `Damala Badara Akon Thiam` is the surname?

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I am not targeting general usage. Only [name name ... surname] format

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution is good except if the name starts with spaces it gets those spaces in the name. e.g. `  Sophie Loren Turner`

Comment: Then use `^\s*([A-Za-z ]+?)\s+([A-Za-z]+)$`. Or better - `^([A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*) ([A-Za-z]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really just interested in getting the first two names, there's nothing wrong with repeating the capture group with a non-captured space in the middle.

```
^([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z]+)+
```

[image]

Alternatively, complementing @Wiktor Stribiżew's answer to exclude spaces in the beginning, you could do:

```
^\s*([A-Za-z ]+) ([A-Za-z]+)$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one `(.*?)\s([\w-]+)$`

Group 1 : name

Group 2 : surname

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jifEi/1/)